# Spring @Scheduled within a @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

When I run the following class,the method "mywork()" will not be scheduled by Spring.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void mywork(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Bean(name = "propertyConfigurer")
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer(){
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        return ppc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }
}
```

But if I delete the Bean definition of propertyConfigurer,it will work normally.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void mywork(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Who can tell me why?

Comment: Probably because you try to do everything in the same class, which is a bad idea, the Configuration class should do only contain configuration, not logic.

Comment: When using `@Bean` , Spring will create a proxy for the `@Configuration` class. Making the `@Scheduled` unreadable because the method will be proxied (and as annotations aren't inherited it will not be visible). An `@Configuration` should be just that configuration it shouldn't contain logic etc.

Comment: One more point, I don't think if you remove bean definition for propertyConfigurer this will work.(as long as you have `@Configuration`)

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the comments it's because you're doing application logic in your configuration bean.

Classes annotated with `@Configuration` is just that - configuration, these are the code-equivalents of the old XML configuration and should only contain code to set up the application.

Recurring tasks and functionality should be inside classes annotated with `@Component` (or a meta-annotation which includes `@Component` such as `@Controller` or `@Service`), or classes that are instantiated from methods annotated with `@Bean`, or registered in some other way with the context.

Now, as to why it doesn't work when you've got a bean method in your configuration:

It may be as M. Deinum says that it's because your class is being proxied, but Spring has no trouble finding `@Scheduled` annotations on regular beans that have been proxied so I doubt it's that.

The more likely reason is that the `@Bean` annotation makes Spring consider your configuration class part of the wiring of the application (which makes sense - that's what it's supposed to be) and as such it may be created before the [`ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) which of course means that the post-processor will never see the `@Scheduled` annotation on your configuration class and therefore never register it with the scheduler.

**TL;DR**

Don't put application logic in the configuration.